# SQL String - make sure 2 results per group / split numbers in fild and count / quicker way

Tags: mysql, sql

This is really 3 questions about this single string.

```
select * 
from RPcards 
where norunners = "8" 
  and fcplace = 1 
  and right(form,3) like '%1%' or norunners = "8" 
  and fcplace = 1 and right(form,3) like '%2%' or norunners = "8" 
  and fcplace = 1 and right(form,3) like '%3%' or norunners = "8" 
  and fcplace = 2 and right(form,3) like '%1%' or norunners = "8" 
  and fcplace = 2 and right(form,3) like '%2%' or norunners = "8" 
  and fcplace = 2 and right(form,3) like '%3%'
```

1. This would be my lesson learned question really as to how I could improve the current string by perhaps shortening the where clause?
2. I would like to ensure that the results selected have 2 results grouped by the field [title] no less and no more
3. I would like to count the last 3 digits in [fcplace]. The current format will look like this '121' or '12-34' or perhaps just '12'. I want to select a maximum of 3 digits and get the total. So the above examples would look like the following: '121' = 4, '12-34' = 9 and '12' would equal 3.

working example would be:

[image]

the end results would be this:

[image]

Only 8 runners in the race.
Only 2 with a 1 and a 2 under fcplace
and the form count added up from the last 3 digits

Comment: If you combine `and` and `or` in the same condition without parentheses the query is almost certainly not doing what you expect it to do.

Comment: Can you give us data sample and what you are expecting?

Comment: really hope the edit helps